# How to Copy Paste Formula in Excel But Skip 1 Cell

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I am working on my report using WPS Office Excel (it is almost same like Microsoft Excel), I have 2 sheet For example, My report sheet is called "Report" and my data sheet is called "Data".

In my "Report" sheet I need to copy paste formula like this

from Cell AP12

```
=((+Data!BK12*$P$11)+(Data!BL12*$Q$11))/$R$11
```

To Cell AQ12, I need the Cell AQ12 to become like this

```
=((+Data!BM12*$P$11)+(Data!BN12*$Q$11))/$R$11
```

But when I copy paste here's what happen in cell AQ12

```
=((+Data!BL12*$P$11)+(Data!BM12*$Q$11))/$R$11
```

Can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=(offset(+Data!BK12;;-2+ROWS(A$1:A1)*2;;)*$P$11)+(offset(+Data!BL12;;-2+ROWS(A$1:A1)*2;;)*$Q$11))/$R$11`

Comment: If you drag the formula down it will skip two columns from BK12 and two from BL12.

Comment: I have a version of Excel that uses `;` instead of `,`, so you probably need to use: `=(offset(+Data!BK12,,-2+ROWS(A$1:A1)*2,,)*$P$11)+(offset(+Data!BL12,,-2+ROWS(A$1:A1)*2,,)*$Q$11))/$R$11`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, I just wonder what is the function of -2+ROWS(A$1:A1)*2;; ? Can I write =(offset(+Data!BK12;;2)*$P$11) ? And I'm sorry I forgot to tell you that I copy to the right.

Comment: Offset starts position from the first argument (cell BK12 in this case). 2nd argument is the number of rows down from that position, 3rd argument the number of columns aside from starting position and arg. 4 and 5 are for height and width.

Comment: If you change the formula to the following you can copy to the right, instead of down: ’=(offset(+Data!BK12,,-2+Columns(A$1:A1)*2,,)*$P$11)+(offset(+Data!BL12,,-2+Columns(A$1:A1)*2,,)*$Q$11))/$R$11’

Comment: Sorry, answering from phone, so hard to find correct character for code..

Comment: It simply counts the number of Columns from your starting position and multiplies by 2. So every cell to the right it adds 2. I start with -2, because the offset of Columns to the right from your starting position should be 0: (-2+(1 Columns *2)) = 0.

Comment: Oh an the $ locks the position of the row in the case above, so you should use: `=(offset(+Data!BK12,,-2+Columns($A1:A1)*2,,)*$P$11)+(offset(+Data!BL12,,-2+Columns($A1:A1)*2,,)*$Q$11))/$R$11`